# How to access nested Part properties in Email Workflow?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I have a Registration ContentType, which contains a ContentPicker field for a Building Item, which contains a Geolocation Part with some properties like Latitude and Longitude.

When a new Registration is Published, it triggers a custom Workflow that sends out an email. In the body of the email I can get to the fields of the Building using tokens like this: `{Content.Fields.Registration.Building.Content.Fields.Building.Address}`

How can I get to the property values of the Geolocation Part contained within the Building? Can I do something like this? `{Content.Fields.Registration.Building.Content.Parts.Geolocation.Latitude}`

I'm new to Orchard and I can't figure out how it's structured. Can this be done out of the box or will I have to write a custom token?

Answer (score 1):

If you know which content item to take from the content picker field (for example if it always is only one), then the following might work:

```
{Content.Fields.Registration.Building.Content.Fields.Building.ContentItems[0].Geolocation.Latitude}
```

This is assuming your Building field is configured to pick content types with a Geolocation part

Comment: I was hopeful but unfortunately it doesn't work either. As far as I can tell, the only solution is to create a custom Token. http://arkleseizure.net/custom-tokens-in-orchard-cms helped me on the way.